# How to say fractions like "7/8" or "546/823"

Tags: pronunciation, numbers, fractions

I have come across the following three spoken variants for the fraction ⅞:

1. Seven by eight
2. Seven over eight
3. Seven into eight

I am also aware of *seven-eighths* but I don't want to use that as it isn't practical for larger numbers. As an Indian, the most common variant I have heard is the first one but somehow that doesn't seem right. Besides, since English isn't our native language, I wouldn't want to trust it. I want to know from native speakers what they use and what's the correct way to refer to such numbers.

To make things even more complicated, most Indians use the third variant to mean something like *7×8*, which I guess should be more appropriately referred to as *seven times eight*.

Comment: I have mostly heard the second variant. The first appears in certain special cases, such as "pi by two". But I'm not sure "five hundred and forty six over eight hundred and twenty three" is any better than "five hundred and forty six eight hundred and twenty thirds".

Comment: For your question, there is no right or wrong, there is only clear or unclear.  For something long, like Simon B's example, I'd say five-four-six divided by eight-two-three.  And I'd say it twice, or ask the person I was talking to, to read it back.  (For something short, like 31/32, I'd say thirty-one over thirty-two.)

Comment: For those who disagree with the notion that the *seven eighths* style of pronunciation "isn't practical for larger numbers", see [this other question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263137/how-to-pronounce-fractions-larger-than-a-twentieth-where-the-last-digit-of-the).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where does one encounter fractions like 546/832?  I remember seeing these kinds of ungainly numbers in math class and my teachers always used x over y.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There could be some differences between English speaking countries, but in Australia only "seven over eight" would be understood as 7/8.

"Seven by eight" could be interpreted as 7x8 but could also be interpreted as the dimensions of a rectangle (length by width).

"Seven into eight" would be interpreted as 8/7.

Comment: Also seven on eight.

Comment: And then there's the special case _one into zero_, which I would interpret as _Ø_.

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody has mentioned the simpler "seven eighths" or "five sixths" style for simple fractions.

Comment: @Polynomial: that's probably because Amit did mention them and say he did not want to use them.

Comment: In the UK likewise: only the _over_ variant would be understood.

Comment: @ColinFine Oh yes, so he did. I blame a lack of coffee for my blindness.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet one into zero is not a special case. It would be understood as 0/1.  It just so happens that 0/1 = 0.

Comment: @JoAnne It's special in that it's the only one that, if taken literally, yields a letter.

Comment: @JoAnne I realise that. I was a typographical joke. There is also a difference between between the letter Ø and the mathematical symbol ∅, which is deliberately based on neither O nor 0—not to mention the difference between the number 1 and the solidus ⁄ (which also differs from the slash used in Ø); so taken literally, it doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: For the mixed fraction 35 436/673, is it correct to read 'thirty five and four hundred thirty six over six hundred seventy three'?

Answer (score 6):

Larger numbers such as *546/823* are normally said as *five hundred and forty-six **over** eight hundred and twenty-three*.

Answer (score 2):

Seven eighths is quite feasible and is the same with almost all fractions: the numerator in cardinal numbers and the denominator in ordinal numbers unless the denominator is not a simple number.

Comment: Amit explicitly said he didn't want to use this, as it's not practical for larger numbers. -1.

Comment: @ColinFine: But OP also said he is not a native English speaker and he would like to hear from native English speakers to see what they use. As a native English speaker, I can say that *seven eighths* is by far the predominant way I've heard the fraction 7/8 spoken. In fact, I'm pretty sure I've never heard anything *but* that form except in math class.

Comment: "Not practical for larger numbers" might mean "ambiguous". Is *three hundred and twenty seven thousandths* 300.027 or 0.327 or 320/7000?

Answer (score 2):

[Oregon State Standard document](http://www.ode.state.or.us/teachlearn/testing/admin/alt/ea/2-guidelines-for-the-math-read-aloud-accommodation-for-2012-2013-(3).pdf) Numbers are read according to their length. Common fraction denominators use ordinal numbers (*third*, *eighth*, etc.). Otherwise, number *over* number.

Answer (score 0):

As native English speakers in the US, we commonly pronounce 7/8 as "seven eighths".
Smaller fractions can get to be an ungainly mouthful quite quickly and certainly take a but more time to say correctly. eg. 43/54 would be "forty-three fifty-fourths" and 327/1000 would be "three-hundred, twenty-seven thousandths" and 693/4697 "six-hundred, ninety-three four-thousand, six-hundred, ninety-sevenths"...but that's leaning towards the impractical as mentioned by Peter S!