# How to pronounce fractions with denominators larger than 20 where the last digit of the denominator is 1 or 2? eg 4/31

Tags: word-usage, pronunciation, mathematics, transatlantic-differences, fractions

**Disclaimer**: I speak British English.  I've noticed a lot of differences between the way Americans and Brits pronounce numbers.<sup>1</sup>  Since the question concerns this, I thought it might be appropriate to draw attention to it case we inadvertently confuse each other.  **My question is not about these differences, I just wish to highlight them in case they cause confusion.**

<sup>1. You seem to happily call a quarter "a fourth" sometimes,

we always call 131 "one hundred **and** thirty one",

we pronounce double digits in phone numbers like 12449 as "one two double four nine", and

I think we are much more likely to use expressions like "thirteen hundred" to mean 1300.</sup>

---

### Question

When talking about fractions, I have frequently heard

```
1/2    a half
1/3    a third
1/4    a quarter
1/8    an eighth
1/64   a sixty fourth
1/56   a fifty sixth
```

etc.

Essentially the rule seems to be that, except for "a whole", "a half", and "a quarter", the word matches the ordinal number; that is to say:

```
    Numeral       Ordinal         Fractional
    one           first           whole
    two           second          half
    three         third           third
    four          fourth          quarter
    five          fifth           fifth
    six           sixth           sixth
    fifty-seven   fifty-seventh   fifty-seventh
```

Even though <sup>1</sup>/<sub>4</sub> is a quarter, <sup>1</sup>/<sub>64</sub> is a sixty-fourth.

So what’s <sup>1</sup>/<sub>62</sub>?  A  *sixty-twoth*?  A *sixty-second*? Surely not a sixty-half!

I know that simply saying *one over sixty-two* can usually work, but I'm asking specifically for *the word itself*, i.e.  if I divide a huge pizza into 21 pieces, what are the pieces?  Other than baker’s twentieths.

**Summary:** Can anyone point me to any sources (whether style guides or common usage studies or anything else) that discuss the pronunciation of fractions; specifically one that discusses this *separately* from ordinal numbers, rather than how to form ordinal numbers in the first place.

Comment: I always go "... twentyoneth, twentytooth, twentythreeth, ...".  (But I suppose I would call that microscopic piece of pizza "one twentyfirst", if I were worried about getting a strange look from the orderly at this resort where I'm staying.)

Comment: it's a big pizza.  edited for clarification

Comment: The question that this is supposedly a duplicate of was not nearly as specific as this one, nor did the answers to that question address the specific issues raised here. The aims of the two questions are clearly divergent. The guidance of "If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question" is pretty frustrating, because the question asked here (by Some_Guy) **is** that new question.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the cited question: that one specifically excludes the usual "seven eighths" type of expression (dunno why), and doesn't really even mention the real question here, i.e. what happens to 1 and 2 when they happen to be the last digit of the denominator.

Comment: @tchrist: please re-read both questions. They are definitely not duplicates.

Comment: @Marthaª Fine, have it your way. I look forward to seeing your vote about missing research, too broad, or any of the others that here apply. The idea that North American and Insular English diverge in this is curious, and there is no suggested Insular English version provided, despite all the "you are different from me" stuff.

Comment: Hi tchrist, the question I believe you linked to was: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208146/how-to-say-fractions-like-7-8-or-546-823  .  The difference as I see it is that the questioner (as a non native english speaker) simply wanted to know any correct way to naturally pronounce fractions (i.e. "one over x").  My question specifically concerns the grammar rules related to pronouncing fractions as "eigths" etc. , rather than simply how to find any way to pronounce a fraction.  I will edit my question to try and emphasize this.  cont.

Comment: cont.  The British/American English stuff is by the by; and does not differentiate this question in any way.   I simply raised it as, since there are so many other differences in the pronunciation of numbers, I wanted to preclude the possibility that this question's goal be obfuscated by dialectical differences

Comment: Also, I just want to thank you for your helpful edits to my question.  I haven't been on stackexchange that long and I must say that so far my experience of the community has been very positive. The common practice of helpful collaboration (specifically helpful rewordings, and markdown improvements) really set this site apart from others in terms of efficiently finding good answers to questions.

Comment: The basic formula for rational numbers is _`Cardinalnumber`-`Ordinalnumber`_ in speech. Thus _three-fourths_. `Ordinalnumber` is plural if `Cardinalnumber` is plural, which it is except for rationals with a numerator of 1. So most of them are plural. The formula for ordinal numbers has irregularities, but fewer than 10, and they're only in the last morpheme; i.e, _seven thousand one hundred thirty-**one/two/three/four/five/six/seven/eight/nine**_ vs _seven thousand one hundred thirty-**first/second/third/fourth/fifth/sixth/seventh/eighth/ninth**_. Suffix -th, plural -ths.

Comment: I'm looking for a citation, this doesn't add anything to existing answers.  Also, as made abundantly clear in the question, this is not a question asking how to form ordinal numbers.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be clear (if the responses you already got are not satisfactory there must be some misunderstanding). Fractions are not pronounced any differently than ordinals except for half and quarter, which you can consider as special cases.

Comment: Please re-edit this question; it's far too complex for "are there any official rules on how to pronounce fractions ending with a 1 or 2, preferably in British English."

Comment: Apart from anything else, one-thirtieth is actually smaller than one-twentieth.

Comment: @msam The problem wasn't incorrect answers, just that once I set a bounty (for a well-sourced answer) I was just just getting a flood of people saying a bunch of stuff that had already been said in previous answers, but without giving any sources

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You asked for sources.

- Americans pronounce fractions with denominators ending with 1, 2, 3, as in *twenty-firsts, twenty-seconds, twenty-thirds*. For confirmation, here is a definition from
  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thirty-second), one of the canonical American dictionaries.

> **thirty-second** 2 : the quotient of a unit divided by 32 :  one of 32 equal parts of anything <one *thirty-second* of the total>

The word *thirty-twoth* does not appear in the *Merriam-Webster* dictionary, no matter how you spell it. While a few people may use *thirty-twoth*, it's definitely non-standard.

- There is a difference when the denominator is 4. Americans use both *fourths* and *quarters* for one piece of something divided into four equal parts (except for hours, which are always *quarter hours*) while in the U.K., these are usually *quarters*. 
  [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fourth) has

> **fourth** 2. chiefly *North American* A quarter:
>   '*nearly three fourths of that money is now gone*'

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fourth) has both

> **fourth** : one of four equal parts of something
>     **quarter** : one of four equal parts of something

Comment: @PeterShor thanks for the concise, to the point, well sourced answer :)

Comment: Of note, when the denominator of a fraction is 4, then "fourth(s)" or "quarter(s)" maybe be used: 1/4 = one fourth or one quarter, and 3/4 = three fourths or three quarters. However, if the denominator of a fraction is not 4 but is an integer that has 4 as its last digit (in the ones or units place), then only "fourth(s)" may be used: 3/34 = three thirty-fourths. "Quarters" is not used in such a case.

Answer (score 18):

In the US, the general rule is the ordinal form is based on the last element in the numeral.

> - sixty-eighth
> - one hundred twenty-ninth
> - one thousandth
> - one thousand-seventh

This does not change when the discussing the denominator of fractions, regardless of whether the numerator is singular or plural

> - one thirteenth
> - one sixty-first
> - three thirty-fourths
> - six twentieths

There are exceptions

> - first
> - second
> - third
> - fifth (although this seems to be a phonetic morph of *fiveth*)
> - half
> - whole
> - quarter

The exceptions carry over to more complex ordinals

> - sixty-second
> - three thirty-thirds

**Supplement** (based on OP's further comments)

The fractional form, at least in US usage, uses the ordinal form for the denominator with only three (I think) exceptions - *whole*, *half* and *quarter*. And *quarter* is also regularly expressed as *fourth*.

Specifically 1/62 is either *one sixty-second* or *a sixty-second*. The 21 pizza slices are each *one twenty-first* of the pie (hardly worth eating!).

As to the footnotes, 131 is either *one hundred thirty one* or less commonly *one hundred **and** thirty one*. If it were the denominator of the fraction 1/131, it would be *one one hundred thirty-first*.

The pronunciation of multi-digit numbers varies based on what the numbers are used for. Telephone numbers are read differently from monetary numbers or counts of widgets, and there are variations within categories depending on the number (area code *212* is almost always pronounced *two one two*, rarely *two twelve*, never *two hundred twelve*, but area code *800* is read *eight hundred*). If you want to discuss that issue, it probably warrants a separate question.

Comment: I think the OP doesn't reallize that denominatorrs are ordinals, but your first sentence seems to assume they already know that.

Comment: Why is *fifth* an exception?

Comment: @T.Verron, if it weren't an exception, we would say "five-th".

Comment: Oh never mind, sorry, I thought you were still talking about the relationship between ordinals and fractions. But rereading the answer now, isn't it clear that the OP knows how to form ordinals?

Comment: If "fifth" is an exception then arguably "eighth" and "ninth" are too (cf. "eightth" and "nineth").

Comment: @j_random_hacker: *eighth* and *ninth* are exceptions only so far as spelling; they're pronounced regularly.

Comment: Hi, just to clarify. my question is not concerning what the ordinal form of numbers is in English.  My question concerns when the ordinal form matches the pronunciation of a fraction, and when it doesn't.  For example, a half and a quarter are **not** ordinals

Comment: Your answer seems to be concerning forming ordinals in English, and, while well constructed, doesn't address the substance of the question.

Answer (score 12):

Definitely  a sixty-first and a sixty-second as far as I am concerned - no doubt about it.  (Mid to South England)

Not that either would come up very often!

Answer (score 2):

- 1/21: a twenty-first, or
- 1/22: one twenty-second
- 7/21: seven twenty-firsts
- 8/22: eight twenty-seconds

Answer (score 2):

I feel that while "a thirty-second" is a perfectly good way to express 1/32, it's ambiguous and unusual. I would want to add the slightly archaic "part" onto the end: "a thirty-second part of this pizza" etc.

Comment: I think that's why some people find themselves using the clearly clunky "thirty twoth".  It may be odd sounding, and said with a sense of irony, but it's also unambiguous

Answer (score 0):

When using fractions in speech, the numerator is properly spoken as a cardinal ("one", "two", "three"). Except in certain cases, the denominator is properly spoken as an ordinal ("third", "fourth", "fifth"). The exceptions are "whole" (one part) and "half" (two parts). There is at least one alternate denominator where "quarter" can be used instead of "fourth".

When speaking numbers in American English, "and" properly indicates a decimal point or the breaking point between the whole and fractional parts of a compound fraction; it doesn't belong anywhere else. British English doesn't have this prescription and practice certainly deviates from this in America as well, introducing the potential for confusion.

In American English, the numeral 131 would properly be read "one hundred thirty-one", though, as you indicated, it would be common to hear it as "one hundred *and* thirty-one". The fraction 1/131 would be read "one one-hundred-thirty-first", "one over one hundred thirty-one", or "one over one hundred and thirty-one", but "one one-hundred-and-thirty-first" certainly sounds wrong to my ear. The confusion enters when someone says something like "one hundred and thirty-one thousandths": Are we talking about 131/1000 (0.131) or 100-31/1000 (100.031)?

Music is one of the few places where you'll encounter these sorts of fractions anymore because note durations are negative powers of two. Instead of going with a long stream of semi-, hemi-, and demi- prefixes, the ordinal is used in English, so you will encounter:

- whole notes and whole rests
- half notes and half rests
- quarter notes and quarter rests
- eighth notes and eighth rests
- sixteenth notes and sixteenth rests
- thirty-second notes and thirty-second rests
- sixty-fourth notes and sixty-fourth rests
- one-hundred-twenty-eighth notes and one-hundred-twenty-eighth rests

It's rare to see sixty-fourth notes or one-hundred-twenty-eighth notes, but the language of music certainly allows for it. Note "thirty-second notes": Per the rule, this complies with using the ordinal to speak the denominator.

Comment: There's confusion using the American way, as well. Does *one thousand three hundred twenty-sevenths* mean 1000/327 or 1300/27? If you inserted the *and*, it would be unambiguous: 1000/327. This is why you should always read complicated fractions as *one thousand **over** three hundred twenty-seven*.

Comment: You're right, though the use of "and" could still be ambiguous: we might be talking about 1320/7. It's the nature of English. It helps me appreciate the Japanese method, which would roughly translate to "131 of 1,000 parts" or whatever fraction you actually wanted to use.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with "chasly from uk" and add that (1) the same applies in the City of London and (2) from "Dizionario di Inglese - Volume Secondo - Italiano-Inglese (Paravia 2002, but originally Oxford University Press 2001): 21° = twenty-first, 22° = twenty-second, 31° = thirty-first, 32° = thirty-second, etc.